# Why linux version of system binary file is not consistent with system release version?

Tags: linux, file, kernel

When use file command to check property of binary file, I notice that the output of something like this:

```
$ file /bin/ls
ls: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=9567f9a28e66f4d7ec4baf31cfbf68d0410f0ae6, stripped

$ file /bin/pwd
pwd: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=fb34777a0e4532338c1f64bec0a8372ee619b9e7, stripped

$ uname -sr
Linux 4.19.9-arch1-1-ARCH
```

There is "for GNU/linux 3.2.0" in the output.

I had test that on both Ubuntu 18.04 (kernel version 4.15) and Arch linux (kernel version 4.19), but the file property is always "linux 3.2.0" for the system binary files.

I would like to know what does this tag mean, and why it is not consistent with system kernel version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tag shows that the [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) binary was compiled with a glibc that produces binaries which require this specific minimun linux kernel version to run.
The version number is set at glibc's [compile time](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Configuring-and-compiling.html) using config option *--enable-kernel*, and is copied by the linker on the binary's SHT_NOTE section (from where it is read by the file command).

Comment: Thank you @Achilleas Kotsis. But why 3.2.0 is so special?  Any why different linux release use same version constraint?

Comment: You can see the [API changes](http://man7.org/tlpi/api_changes/#Linux-3.2). This is most probably a generic glibc requirement for versions [newer than 2.24](https://abi-laboratory.pro/?view=changelog&l=glibc&v=2.24)